# SASS Mixin Rewrite & (ampersand)

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

I'm trying to write a mixin that will modify the parent selector on output. The idea is that in cases where a mixin is called, the parent selector will need to have a string replacement done on it. I have most of this working, but I can't figure out how to swallow the `&`.

```
.test {
  @include alt_parent() {
    content: 'test';
  }
}
```

The mixin is something like this:

```
@mixin alt_parent() {
  #{str-replace(unquote("#{selector_append(&)}"), "s", "x")} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

I have the string replacement working, so that isn't the problem. What I get is this (and I understand why):

```
.test .text {
  content: 'test';
}
```

What I want is this:

```
.text {
  content: 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `@at-root` directive to defeat the automatic inclusion of the selectors represented by `&`.

http://alwaystwisted.com/articles/2014-03-08-using-sass-33s-at-root-for-piece-of-mind

```
@mixin alt_parent($parent) {
    @at-root {
        #{str-replace(unquote("#{selector_append(&)}"), "s", "x")} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```